# In Objective-C `malloc`, what is the meaning of the default initialized bits?

Tags: macos, memory, malloc, bit-manipulation

Preface I'm pretty sure calling `malloc` in Objective-C is just executing the C implementation, because it's included from `stdlib.h`, but I just specified Objective-C because I'm not sure if it's relevant.  This is for a macOS app (also not sure if that's relevant)

When our code executes `malloc`:

```
mMaskData = malloc(mHeight * mMaskRowBytes);
```

The values in memory at `*mMaskData` are:

> FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
>   FF 00 60 7C 1E 01 00 00 00 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F 1F
>   1F 1F 1E 14 13 13 11 07 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05
>   05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05
>   05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05 05
>   05 05 05 05 05 05

Why is this?  What are the F's, followed by an address? (00607Ç1E01000000, not sure what this is, but it kind of looks like an object address)
What are the 1F's?  What is the 05?

The main reason I'm curious is because the next line of code is:

```
  memset(mMaskData, 0, mHeight * mMaskRowBytes);
```

Which sets all of the bits to 0, so the memory at `*mMaskData` look like this:

> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00

In my mind, calling `malloc` would allocate memory and initialize the bits to 0, so we wouldn't need to call `memset`?

Comment: `malloc` does not initialise memory - you would need to use `calloc` if you want it zeroed, or explicitly zero it with e.g. `memset` after allocation, as per above. Note that malloc/calloc/memset/free are all part of the C standard library - this has little to do with Objective-C *per se*.

Comment: a previous developer actually changed the code from `calloc` -> `malloc`.  Unfortunately the commit message is "merged dev1 to trunk" in 2012...  Is there any reason why `malloc` would be called instead?

Comment: `malloc` is faster than `calloc` since it doesn't have to explicitly zero the memory.

Comment: If the memory does not need to be initialised to zero then malloc would be preferred (for efficiency reasons). OTOH calloc is preferred over malloc + memset.

Comment: So it looks like this was just a developer error that goes back 7 years...
Somebody added `memset(mMaskData, 0, mHeight * mMaskRowBytes);` 7 years ago.  Then 4 years ago somebody changed `calloc` to `malloc`.

Comment: I should be able to safely change `malloc` back to `calloc`, and remove the `memset` call right?

Comment: Yep - if you're going to fix it properly then just use calloc, otherwise stick with malloc + memset. Be careful with the calloc parameters though - it would be: `malloc(mHeight * mMaskRowBytes)` -> `calloc(mHeight, mMaskRowBytes)`.

Comment: Got it.  Changed it and it works just as it did previously.  Thanks for the help clarifying Paul :)